# Местоимение «сам»

Tags: местоимение

Скажите, пожалуйста, местоимение «сам» может быть подлежащим?

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, синтаксическая роль местоимения *сам* будет зависеть от позиции в предложении: 
**Сам сделай** 
*сам (кто?)=ты* подлежащее

**Сделай сам** 
*сам (как?)=самостоятельно, своими руками* обстоятельство

Хотя многое от контекста зависит.

Но то что может ли быть подлежащим - да, конечно, может.

Comment: Позиция здесь не слишком показательна. "Сам сделай" = "самостоятельно сделай". Я тоже склоняюсь, что в принципе подлжеащим быть может, но любой конкретный пример можно оспорить.

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь, об этом можно поспорить. Формальная грамматика, похоже, однозначного ответа не даёт. По крайней мере если речь идёт о местоименном существительном. Фразу "сам делает" можно трактовать и "делает - кто?", и "делает - как?". В первом случае ничего не остаётся, как признать, что "сам" выступает в роли подлежащего.

Answer (score 0):

Может. Например: *Сам не понял.*  *Не понял* - сказуемое, *сам* - подлежащее.